# Extended hours in php

Tags: php, mysql, datetime

I have been searching for a while now regarding on how to format hours in php that will show 000:00:00 instead of 00:00:00.

I need this to calculate the duration of records with start and end Date with a datetime data type in mysql.

The problem with my current format ('H:m:s') is it only count 24 hours and when the duration goes higher than that, it will show 01:00:00 instead of 25:00:00.

Comment: Don't use `date()`.  A specific date has only 24 hours.

Comment: Yep, you will have to create your own Time object in order to accomplish that. The standard data time only works with 24 hours.

Comment: @AbraCadaver so should I use time as datatype in mysql instead of datetime?

Comment: That will work for storage in MySQL to a point (about 1 month worth of time), but in PHP you will probably use a string, or better an array or a custom object.

Comment: I really need to input and get the records with 000:00:00 as a format in order for me to get the average time and also compare this to other time. Is there any way for PHP to output the hours like that instead of having the 24-hour format.

Answer (score 1):

Try [TIMEDIFF()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_timediff) function in MySQL

Example:

```
SELECT TIMEDIFF('2008-12-31 23:59:59.000001',
             '2008-12-30 01:01:01.000002');
        -> '46:58:57.999999'
```

Comment: `The result returned by TIMEDIFF() is limited to the range allowed for TIME values.` which is from `-838:59:59` to `838:59:59`. Hope this is enough for OP.

Comment: i also need to show the duration in a table when there is no end date in my records yet. duration = CurrentDate - startDate (something like this)

Comment: @Ely: `IFNULL(endDate, NOW())`? Like `TIMEDIFF(IFNULL(endDate, NOW()), startDate)`

Comment: Ely, you can store the result of this query in a column @Glavić that's a good idea